# Software for creating the QSAR model?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software, molecular-structure

There is the .csv file with a large amount of descriptors and known experimental activity.

Which software can find and **describe** model for prediction. Most important - numerical representation of model - which descriptor is taken with coefficients.

I am looking for any software, not necessary free.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple packages capable of designing [QSAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_structure%E2%80%93activity_relationship) models.

At a basic level, QSAR is about building a statistical model fitting some property/activity based on a set of multiple descriptors. You can use any multivariate statistical package to do that, including [R](http://r-project.org) (as indicated in the [other answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/47166/5017)) or [Python](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/1595/42723).

If you're new, I would *highly* suggest [KNIME](https://www.knime.org) an open "platform" for connecting multiple software packages for analyzing data. It's heavily used for QSAR.

There are several examples for KNIME QSAR, e.g. [using CheS-Mapper](http://ches-mapper.org/wiki/index.php?title=KNIME_Node_Tutorial_-_Visual_validation_of_a_QSAR_prediction) - a quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=knime+qsar) turns up several.

A critical concern, though is [validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_structure%E2%80%93activity_relationship#Evaluation_of_the_quality_of_QSAR_models), either through separate training and test sets, cross-validation / bootstrapping methods, or other techniques. It's easy to design models that fit noise.

Answer (score 3):

Package ‘rcdk’ https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcdk/index.html start here ...